# using loop to check and remove a className from class name string and add another className to the element which triggers the event

Tags: javascript, html, css

it is fairly simple.

I want to make a `current` class and put it on a link that is currently active

like this : `<li class="li current"><a>Link1</a></li>`

but before that, the JS should get all of element with `class="li"`, loop through it and remove the `class=" current"` if any.

after looping end, then add `class=" current"` to the element which triggers the event.

for example if user clicks on **link3** then JS should remove the `class=" current"` on **link1** and then add `class=" current"` on **link3**

it would look like this : `<li class="li current"><a>link3</a></li>`

it looks like I cannot use `getElementsByClassName()` for event listener. what should I do to make an event listener then?

the **HTML**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
 var et = document.getElementsByClassName("li");
 for(i=0; i <et.length; i++){
   et[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    funclink(event);
   });
  };
});

function funclink(event){
 //first get all element with class "li" and remove class " current"
 //then add class " current" to the element which triggers the event
 var slink = document.getElementsByClassName("li");
 for(i =0; i < slink.length; i++){
  slink[i].className = slink[i].className.replace(" current","");
 }
 event.currentTarget.className += " current";
}
```

```css
.current {
color : orange;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navmenu">
 <li class="li current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li class="li"><a href="#">Call Service</a>
  <li class="li"><a class="a-left" href="#">Rental</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a class="a-left" href="#">Sales</a></li>
  
 </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: You will have to loop over elements and add eventlistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented before, you will have to loop over elements to add eventListener. `document.getElementsByClassName`  will return a NodeList.

Also, if you are only calling your function with event param, you can just pass function ref instead.

Also, instead again fetching all `li`s, just fetch those `li`s that has class `current`. This will reduce number of iterations.

You should use `classList` instead of `className`. It has many helpful methods like `add`, `remove` and `toggle`.

---

**Edit 1**

As you need to retain the selected `li` even after refresh, you will have to use client storage or query param to tell your JS about the selected element.

For security reasons, SO does not provide access to `localStorage`, so you will have to copy code and debug on local files.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var lis = document.getElementsByClassName("li")
  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].addEventListener("click", funclink.bind(lis[i], i));
  }
  
  initializeUI();
});

function funclink(index, event) {
  var lis = document.querySelectorAll('.li.current');
  for(var i = 0; i< lis.length; i++){
    lis[i].classList.remove('current');
  }
  this.classList.add('current');
  setIndex(index)
}

function initializeUI(){
  var lis = document.querySelectorAll('.li');
  var index = parseInt(locatStorage.getItem('liIndex'));
  lis[index || 0].classList.add("current");
}

function setIndex(index){
  localStorage.setItem("liIndex", index);
}

function blockAnchors(){
  var as = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  for(var i = 0; i< as.length; i++){
    as[i].onclick = function(){ 
      return false 
    }
  }
}
blockAnchors();
```

```css
.current{
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navmenu">
  <li class="li"><a href="?module=home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="?module=service">Call Service</a>
    <li class="li"><a class="a-left" href="?module=rental">Rental</a></li>
    <li class="li"><a class="a-left" href="?module=sales">Sales</a></li>

  </li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** I have added a `blockAnchors` to stop navigation on `a`'s click.  This is just for demonstration.

Comment: yeah I managed to make it work thanks to your comment. but when I click on a link and the page loads, the current class is returned to original element. does that mean I cannot use JS to make the `class=" current"` stays on the active link?

Comment: Does clicking on `a` refreshes the page?

Comment: yes. unfortunately I don't know how to do this using server side language like PHP

Comment: You can use client storage. I have used `llocalStoorage` but you can use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` as per your need. You can check the update

Comment: okay. I just need to digest the information.... I don't know what `setIndex`, `localtstorage` and `lis[index || 0]` means and do

Comment: `setIndex` is a custom function that will set selected elements index in localStorage. `localStorage` is a storage area introduced in HTML5, where we can store data as string. `lis[...]` will fetched mentioned index inside `[]`. And finally `index || 0` is a shortcut to `if(!index) return 0`. Now `index || 0` is an expression which would return first truthy value

Comment: I tried your code. after the page loads/refreshes the current class is still returning to original element.
 what will make it stay on the currently active link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139463/discussion-between-rajesh-and-citra45abadi).

Comment: no sorry. I did not see your edit. it is locatstorage, you are writing that on purpose

Answer (score 0):

Array of elements doesn't have to initialized two times.
Using `li` class is a useless. Modern browsers (IE8+) can use `querySelector()` (`querySelectorAll()`) (similiar functionality to the jQuery selector).
When document is ready we get array of links in #navmenu, we add listeners to them.

`funclink` function removes all classes from links and then sets class "current" to the element, that has triggered that function.

```js
var slink; //prepare global scope var that will be filled with link elems
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {//wait for document to be loaded
  slink = document.querySelectorAll("#navmenu li");//fill global var with array of link elems
  for (i = 0; i < slink.length; i++) {//add click listener to all link elems
    slink[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      funclink(event);
    });
  }
});

function funclink(event) {
  for (i = 0; i < slink.length; i++)slink[i].className = ""; //remove all current classes
  event.currentTarget.className = "current"; //add current class to the element that triggered fnc
}
```

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}

.current,
.current a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navmenu">
  <li class="current"><a href="#?module=home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#?module=service">Call Service</a>
    <li><a class="a-left" href="#?module=rental">Rental</a></li>
    <li><a class="a-left" href="#?module=sales">Sales</a></li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add explanation as to what and why have you changed. You are answering for readers'

Comment: @Rajesh I think it is pretty self explanatory - updated though... IMO i just made the code a bit cleaner and more effective. (I might be wrong)

Comment: Its not about self explanatory. A reader will have to go through your entire code and then reconcile with OP's code just to understand the difference. Hence explanation is very important. There are many people who do not have knowledge like you have and that makes obvious things confusing

Comment: @Rajesh you are right that i haven't taken newcommers in consideration. Judging from the OP code (if it's his own), i decided to make my answer short, but you are right it wouldn't be so obvious to less experienced coders.